# FetchAttributes from a CloudBlob with Error when trying to know if a blob exists

Tags: c#, azure, blob

We are trying to know if a blob exists, so we are doing a FetchAttributes. It has worked well but in a load test, in thousand of requests, two of the requests failed in this method.

The error was **BlobType of the blob reference doesn't match BlobType of the blob.**

The blob exists.

Do you know if there is an error in the SDK 1.7 for this method?

This is the code, resumed. Thank you.

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount;

CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher(
            (configName, configSettingPublisher) => configSettingPublisher(serviceName));

cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}", accountName, accountKey));

BlobConnection blobConn =
                new BlobConnection(GeneralConstants.GetValue(GeneralConstantsEnum.BlobPersistance), identity);

blobClient = this.Account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);

blobContainer.GetBlobReference(blobName);

CloudBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlobReference(blobName);

blob.FetchAttributes(); //Throws the exception
operation = blob.Metadata["operation"];
productId = blob.Metadata["productId"];
clientId = blob.Metadata["clientId"]; 

workOrders = blob.DownloadText();
```

Comment: Can you share your code? I'm guessing it has something to do with BlobType (Block or Page).